# How to make multi line in textbox MVC?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

How to make multi line in textbox MVC. In web forms I could change it in HTML:

```
TextMode="MultiLine"
```

but how to do this in MVC textbox?

```
  @Html.TextBox("Napisz", null, new { @class = "ostatni" })
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `TextArea` helper method

```
@Html.TextArea("Napisz", null, new { @class = "ostatni" })
```

This will render a textarea, not an input text element with multi line support.

If you want to specify the custom row number and column number, you can specify that in the `htmlAttributes` parameter

```
@Html.TextArea("Napisz", null, new { @class = "ostatni", rows=5, cols="30" })
```

Another thing to note is, **It is not necessary to use these helper methods**. These methods simply generate the htmk markup. So instead of using these helper methods, you are free to write pure markup like this

```
<textarea class="ostatni" cols="30" id="Napisz" name="Napisz" rows="5"></textarea>
```

In asp.net core, we have tag helpers and usage of which is very similar to writing pure html (*it was created for the front end designers who does not need to worry about c#*)

Comment: I think you will need to specify a height, or some rows="" cols="" attributes as well to achieve the multine stuff.

Comment: If you do not specify it will use default values(2 rows,20 columns).

Comment: Cool, I did not know that.